# Gmail to Spreadsheet [GAS]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

【Error】
Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
searchContactMail   @ コード.gs:24

【Code】

```
    function searchContactMail() {
 
  const query = '"no-reply@hojokin-osusume.com "';
  const start = 0;
  const max = 10;
 
  const threads = GmailApp.search(query, start, max);
  const messagesForThreads = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
 
  const values = [];
  for(const messages of messagesForThreads){
    const message = messages[0];
    const record = [
      message.getDate(),
      message.getFrom(),
      message.getSubject(),
      message.getPlainBody().slice(0,200)
    ];
    values.push(record);
  }
 
  if(values.length > 0){
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gs1FPCNtTeBfsG-euGXyTXIxlNh0f0PTeixV595BWjo")
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 2):

About your error of `Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange. searchContactMail @ コード.gs:24`, in your script, `sheet` is a object of Class Spreadsheet from `sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")`. Because in the case of Class Spreadsheet, the argument of `getRange` is only A1Notation. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

When you want to remove this issue, in order to use the method of `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`, `rangehow about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gs1FPCNtTeBfsG-euGXyTXIxlNh0f0PTeixV595BWjo")
```

#### To:

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gs1FPCNtTeBfsG-euGXyTXIxlNh0f0PTeixV595BWjo").getSheets()[0];
```

In this case, the 1st sheet is used. You can use `1, 2, 3,,,` as the index. Or,

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gs1FPCNtTeBfsG-euGXyTXIxlNh0f0PTeixV595BWjo").getSheetByName("###sheetName###");
```

In this case, you can select the sheet name.

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)